# What is the order of complexity of inserting N elements into a List<T> if I don't specify a capacity?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

So let's say I have something like

```
List<int>() numbers = new List<int>();
int num;
while(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
{
    numbers.Add(num);
}
```

and let's say the number of elements added is `N`. I'm wondering whether the total complexity would be described as `O(N)` or `O(N^2)`, when taking into consideration the fact that insertion is "usually" `O(1)` but will be `O(n)` "once in a while" when internally the list needs to be copied into a larger array.

Comment: What did you find in your research on the subject, and how did it fail to answer your question?

Comment: It's amortized `O(n)` for inserting `n` values. Intuitively, it means that even if it's `O(n)` once in a while, over `n` inserts, it averages to `O(n)`.

Comment: Like @IVlad has stated, it would be O(N). To add more to his/her explanation, creating a new array and copying elements is a linear operation, thus you would not have O(N^2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.net uses a variant of the algorithm that allocates an array twice as large when the list is full, copies the existing elements to it and frees the old one, which is basically extending the initial array.

In fact, all languages that provide a List equivalent probably do this, since there is no reason not to.

> and let's say the number of elements added is N. I'm wondering whether the total complexity would be described as O(N) or O(N^2), when taking into consideration the fact that insertion is "usually" O(1) but will be O(n) "once in a while" when internally the list needs to be copied into a larger array.

This is amortized `O(n)` for inserting `n` elements and amortized `O(1)` for inserting one element.

Amortized basically means that the total number of operations to insert `n` elements averages out to `O(n)`, even if one insert might do more operations than another, due to having to extend the array.

To see this, consider the classical algorithm I described in the first paragraph. Let's say our capacity is initially 1. We will count how many operations are performed when the array is extended. When inserting the first element, we have:

```
0
```

operations, because the array is not extended.

Inserting the second element has to copy the existing elements to the new array and only then perform the insertion. For clarity, we will ignore the constants introduced by memory operations. So this is:

```
1
```

operations (copy 1 element, new capacity is 2).

When inserting the third element, we have:

```
2
```

operations (copy 2 elements, new capacity is 4)

When inserting the fourth element, we have `0` operations, because we still have room left.

When inserting the fifth, we have:

```
4
```

operations (copy 4 elements, new capacity is 8).

In general, when inserting the `2^k+1`th element, we will have:

```
2^k
```

operations.

How large can `k` be? `log base 2 of n` (`log n`), because then we will have enough room for our `n` elements.

So the complexity of all resize operations is given by the sum:

```
S = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k, k = log n
S = (1 - 2^k) / (1 - 2) // sum of a geometric progression with ratio 2
  = 2^k - 1
  = 2^(log n) - 1
  = n - 1
  = O(n)
```

So the total complexity is `O(n)` plus another `O(n)` since we didn't count the actual inserts. But this is still `O(n)` in total.

Answer (score -1):

That depends entirely how this instance of List running on this instance of the Framework will grow. Something I can not predict, as the answer might change depending on OS resource, Framework version and how full the list is already. It is a implementation detail.

Obviously giving a capacity will improove performace. If you are not quite certain about the exact number, setting a excess capacity and then using [TrimExcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207.aspx) after all has been added might work. Capacity is only there to avoid the overhead of having to grow the list.

Comment: Entity Framework isn't involved here at all.  It also doesn't depend on the OS or how many items are currently in the list (although the list is created in the code, so we *know* it starts at zero anyway).

Comment: I highly doubt it's so environment-dependent. The classic algorithm for dynamic arrays will be `O(n)`. Note that the question is about big-oh, not performance.

Comment: A simple optimisation of the auto-grow process, would be to take a value based on the current elements. A 1000 entry list is much more likely to need 100 more entries then 10. Opposite for a 5 element List. I did not mention Entity Framework in any way. I gave a link to the basic TrimExcess function wich is around since .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Christopher `List` grows exponentially whenever it's forced to expand the size of the backing array.  It has done so for every version of .NET; that behavior not specific to certain versions, nor have any other approaches been used.  Given that, the Big O value of addition is known (and of course your answer doesn't even mention what it is), so you're not actually answering the question.

Comment: @Servy: So I was right that the amount it grows depends on the current fillsize and that a specific Framework version might choose a different approach (they just do not do right now, wich is different from "never will"). Every question about complexity is about performance in the end. Giving capacity improoves performance, both during growth and later when the GC has to run.  And trim can deal with any excess. How about we allow the Asker to decide what is a viable answer? Maybe my ability to read between the lines was just better then yours this time?

Comment: @Christopher The behavior is described in the documentation, so no, it's not subject to change.  It's not the asker's place alone to give feedback on the quality of answers.  It's the entire community's place.  That's how SO works.  And no, you aren't "reading between the lines" of the question, you just straight up failed to read the actual lines of the question, and have failed to even attempt to answer it.